# Generic class with both constraints T(struct) and Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I'm using `LinQ2SQL` and implemented a user control to edit prices of different entities using data bindings.

```
public partial class PriceControl<TDataSource, TPricesVat, TPriceNet, TPriceGross>
    : ANotifyPropertyXtraUserControl, IPriceControl<TDataSource, TPricesVat, TPriceNet, TPriceGross>
    where TDataSource : class, INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    where TPricesVat : struct
    where TPriceNet : struct
    where TPriceGross : struct
{
}
```

I like to use both types `decimal` and `decimal?`. I'm using in code statements to treat them as necessary. But C# does not accept `decimal?` in order to these type constraints. I found out that `Nullable<T>` is a `struct`, too, but not fully supported like a `struct`.

Is it possible and if so, how to achieve this in the type constraints? I estimate the answer is "No". But perhaps ...

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, that removing the constraints for `TPricesVat`, `TPriceNet` and `TPriceGross` let me compile this code properly, but I have no possibility to force the allowed generic types at design time.

---

**Edit:** This question has been asked due a job I did. But soon after I left and I couldn't close this question with a proper solution. Respecting this Q'n'A platform I left this edit here.

Thanks for all useful mentions.

Comment: Is there a genuine reason to constrain those generic type parameters to be a struct?  The only reason I can see is that you treat a variable of that type in a manner that assumes that it can never be null.  If you're not doing that does the constraint really serve a purpose?

Comment: Why do you need a struct? You could also write something like `where T : decimal, decimal?` instead of `where T : struct`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: I tried to enforce scalar types, because there are price calculations running in the background. I thought using constraints to scalar types and it's nullable counterparts prevents me from checking in code so much.@thefiloe: No I can't. `Invalid constraint type. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.`

Comment: @thefiloe you can't constrain a generic type parameter to a specific `struct` type. `where T: decimal` would mean, "T is decimal or any subtype of decimal", but that wouldn't make much sense since structs don't support inheritance. The constraint `where T: U` is only valid if `U` is either a class or an interface type. Also, you can specify one type and one type only per constraint, `where T: U, X` is not valid.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that removing the constraints for `TPricesVat`, `TPriceNet` and `TPriceGross` let me compile this code properly, but I have no possibility to force the correct usage of generic types allowed at design time.

Comment: Why not just declare all the parameters as type Nullable<decimal>?  You can pass a decimal where a decimal? is expected so isn't that enough to handle all the possibilities?

Comment: Anytime you have more than 1 generic type in a method, scrutinize it carefully to make sure you can't simplify it even more.  Anytime you have more than 2 generic types, rewrite it to have no more than 2 generic types (with a handful of exceptions permitted).  So, use decimal? literally here.  Nothing wrong with good ol' fashioned easy to read and test arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion is correct, you can't do that. You'd have to provide an overload for every method:

```
public partial class PriceControl<TDataSource, TPricesVat, TPriceNet, TPriceGross>
  : ANotifyPropertyXtraUserControl, IPriceControl<TDataSource, TPricesVat, TPriceNet, TPriceGross>
  where TDataSource : class, INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
  where TPricesVat : struct
  where TPriceNet : struct
  where TPriceGross : struct
{

   public void DoSomething(TPriceNet price) {}
   public void DoSomething(TPriceNet? price)
   {
       if(price.HasValue)
           DoSomething(price.Value);
       else
       {
          //throw exception? log? no-op?
       }
   }
}
```

But, like others have asked, why constrain those types to `struct`? Can a `byte` or `SpinWait` be a valid `TPriceNet`?

Comment: The goal is not to force the constraints of `struct`. I'm aware of using `bool` will cause my code to crash because I'm basically handling `decimal` values. It was just the beginning to constrain this generic types properly. Your code is right, if I use methods only, but I'm using properties to get and set values. ... In fact you let me think about removing these properties and use get- and set-methods instead. Should make anything more simple.

Comment: @ChristianRamelow Having two getters and two setters (one nullable, one not) would be the exact same as having two properties. There's no need to replace your properties.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a have method that receives a `decimal` and returns a `decimal?` as it may also work with `int` and `int?` as well

```
public T? DoSomeMath<T>(T value)
   where T: struct
{
   //to return null you can do this
   return default(T);
   //or
   return null;
}
```

*Notice the `?` in the method declaration*

This is the best you can when working with struct and nullables.

It would be nice if i could constraint to  `where T: System.Nullable<T>`.

But **that would mean a paradox:** If `T` is a `System.Nullable<T>` and I receive a `T` as an argument then it means that the `T` inside of `System.Nullable<>` would be itself another `System.Nullable<T>`

Of course that if you already know you'll always work with decimals then there is no need to use a generic, just use the `decimal` directly.

Comment: It's forced by the database design. Changing this design will cause too much side effects in the whole project. It's too big to change now.

Comment: You can always declare a System.Nullable<TPriceNet> inside your method